# How to get random user profiles in SharePoint 2013 restful api?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

In SharePoint 2013 restful api, is there a way to put in the url for user profiles, that you want say 5 random items from the target list? I don't want to download the whole thing and then take 5 random things from that.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of any random function in OData, but one hack could be to fetch lowest and highest user ID, then pick 5 random IDs from that range (either with re-query for holes or fetching more than 5)?

Comment: Just did a [quick test](https://gist.github.com/eirikb/dfd50d981b9e189c68aa) with Angular on 365, and the first ID was 4 and the last was 1073741823, so not such a good idea after all. But that might be special for _System Account_, so you could perhaps filter them out, set a filter with `le 1000000000` or similar...

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of OData supporting any random like methods. I fear you need to do this in at least two http requests. For example:

1. Fetch the Id of the users on the site. The filter ignores the system account.

   ```
   /_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/Items?$select=Id&$filter=Id lt 1073741823
   ```
2. Next step is to pick out random people.

   ```
   var items = d.results.items,
       numPeople = 5,
       peopleIds = [];

   // if we don't have enough people we simply select all the Ids available
   if (items.length < numPeople) {
       for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
           peopleIds.push(items[i].Id);
       }

   // otherwise we loop until we have the amount of people we want
   } else {
       while (peopleIds.length < numPeople) {
           var person = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
           // make sure the Id doesn't exist from before
           if (peopleIds.indexOf(person.Id) === -1) {
               peopleIds.push(person.Id);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Last step is to use the selected Ids to query the rest of the profile information we need.

   ```
   // using join and the Ids to build the filter
   '/_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/Items?$filter=Id eq ' + peopleIds.join(' or Id eq ')
   ```

I realize this isn't ideal if you have thousands of users. But limiting the selected data to a minimum, then doing the randomization logic, then fetching the specific users we wish to know about might just do it.

I guess it will never happen, but in case there are no users, I'd add some sanity checks along the way, especially on the last step.